# When should I create a redis client in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

My question is very simple; should I create a `redis` instance the moment I need it, like inside a function, or create it once globally and reuse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want lowest latency from Redis, you don't want to depend on connection times but instead only round trip command processing times. It's best to create a persistent connection then reuse that connection over a prolonged period of time to communicate with your Redis server.

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to create it once and inject it wherever you need it.